# SQL Server : Instead of trigger update on view; select all columns except a specific one and update the base table record

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have a view which has realField1, RealField2, Realfield3 and many other realfields and a calculated column named `isHighestVersion`.

(realField means a real column within a SQL Server table, column names renamed for brevity).

The view is based on a multi-table query (actually has to refer multiple times to the same base table but SQL Server treats them as multiple different tables) and has one calculated boolean column named `isHighestVersion`. This view does not allow to be directly updated and brings the following error message when trying to:

> Update or insert of view or function 'xyz' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

As I will have many of such views and the fields of the underlying tables and views could change during development time, I want to have a "general" SQL code within the triggers which pulls out all columns (except the `isHighestVersion` column) out of the "inserted" table and then does an update on the correct record within the one real underlying table - of course without the non-existing `ishighestversion` column.

How to do that?

Comment: '"general" SQL code' - yeah, not so much in SQL Server. You either write specific code or try to write dynamic SQL that constructs the specific code at runtime. But it's not going to be pretty and will probably have its own limitations similar to the ones SQL Server imposes (if it was trivial to do this, I'm sure there would be some kind of `ALLOW_DML_IGNORE_COMPUTED_COLUMNS` option for views).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple...you can't. There is no work around here. It violates the limitations of an updatable view. It is clearly indicated as such in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#updatable-views).

> A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that
>   uses other columns.

Comment: Hi Sean, I believe you didn't understand my question. FYI: With "instead of update" triggers, one very well can create a custom update statement which only affects one base table. 
My question was really, how to design this custom update query so that it takes all fields except one specific from the inserted table (this is a special table when using instead of update triggers) and then updates the underlying base table with the values from the "inserted" table.

Comment: Yes I think you are correct I didn't understand what you were asking. FYI, the inserted table is available in ALL triggers, not just instead of triggers. You would need dynamic sql to do this dynamically.